# Version Control for Access VBA code?

Tags: ms-access, version-control, ms-office

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Version control for VBA file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662166/version-control-for-vba-file)

Does any kind of version control exist? 
If no, is there any good solution for collective development of MS Access 2007 database with VBA ?

Comment: remember to search for your question first, please.

Comment: sorry. quick preview search had shown nothing related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only one integrated VC solution for Access is Microsoft Visual Source Safe however it's poor designed and even Microsoft internally avoid from using it ;). Some people call it "Source Destruction System", but I personally know success cases with using it. Generally, it could be a good solution for small and medium projects due to its limitations.

Here is a very critical article about VSS:
http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/windev/sourcesafe.html

The other option is to design your own code to export VBA solution using Application.SaveAsText() - it's partially undocumented feature of Access API.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft have produced a [Source Code Control add-in](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=586912A5-3809-44EF-AC55-43D36ECAB9DE) for Access 2010:

> Source Code Control add-in allows
>   integration with Microsoft Visual
>   SourceSafe or other source code
>   control systems to allow
>   check-in/check-out of queries, forms,
>   reports, macros, modules, and data.
>   You can also see the differences that
>   have been made to your checked out
>   objects.

Answer (score 2):

I work with an Access application and Team Foundation Server Source Control. You need to switch the source control provider Access expects; I used this tool, [Sourcecode Control Switcher](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/sccswitcher.aspx), to do so when we moved from VSS to TFS. Once you've switched, you can setup the source control settings in Access and build a source-control-connected .mdb from TFS. It works nicely.